# Excel VBA copy cell value that is bold over regular values until next bold value then copy that over regular values etc

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone I use Excel 2010 with VB

Ok so I have an issue where I have to copy the bolded cells value from a column into another column AND the same value to be copied until it hits the row with the bolded cell value again and then that value takes over and is copied until another bolded value etc AND when copying the first 2 digits of a number (or characters as I think the numbers are stored as text) are to be deleted.

Can this be done?

I found this code for the copying bolded values into another column:

```
Sub yTekhed()
    For Each cell In [A30:A2557]
        If cell.Font.Bold = True Then
            Debug.Print cell.Row
            cell.Copy Range("I" & Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I figured out the deleting characters, there is a formula =RIGHT(A1; LEN(A1)-2)

But that is as far as I got

I still can't copy bold over regular. So say I have:

**08479**

code

082222

093334

084213

**08572**

code

093212

012321

482123

I want the paste to look like

**08479**

**08479**

**08479**

**08479**

**08572**

**08572**

**08572**

**08572**

So paste the bold value over every regular (non bold) value until the next bold value then copy that one and then paste that value over regular values. Hope this explains it a bit better.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So you want to go through Col A, if it's bold, you want it copied down until the next bold charachter, etc? Do you need it to be copied down because you can also just copy the bold cells on the exact same line. Also what if the first line isn't bold?

Comment: Until the next bold row yes. I don't care if its copied on the same column but I would prefer it to be a different column. I can make the first line bold, myself just for it to have something to copy, again not an issue. Technically I could do this by just copy pasting, but there are over 2500 rows would take me forever to do.

Comment: I mean you have the following `A1: Bold, A2: NB, A3: NB, A4: Bold`. Do you want `B1-B3` to be the value of `B1` or `B1 = A1, B2 = empty, B3 = empty, B4 = A4`?

Comment: Well if B is the column I am pasting to then B1-B3 are all A1 and then B4 is A4

Comment: Weird, but ok, going to add an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub yTekhed()
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Range("A" & i).Font.Bold = True Then
            Range("A" & i).Copy Range("B" & i)
            x = i
        Else
            Range("A" & x).Copy Range("B" & i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I gotta tell you it seems to have worked (its a lot of data and its a bit of a mess). To give you  an explanation as to the purpose, there is this old program from which when I export the data its not very good. And the way data was inserted is also not very good. Anyway I am making a new version of that program with c# and an oracle database that has to abide by all the usual rules. Thing is I have to input the old data into the program and this is unfortunately the way how. Anyway thanks for all your help t.thielemans

Comment: I'm sorry to be bothering you but if u are still reading this is there a way for values which have a * in them to just copy them into another column but the same row. Or to add *. So like if a column row has * add that * to that same row but a different column???

Comment: I'm still reading ;-) So if `A4 = *5` `C4 = *5`, what if it's bold too?